# uname and grub not showing latest updates shown in dpkg -l so can't delete to make space in /boot

Tags: grub2, kernel

I can no longer update ubuntu 16.04 or upgrade to 18.04  as I need to delete some space in /boot. I normally delete the old kernels but the oldest is now 4.4.0.116 which appears to be the running kernel in uname. My latest downloaded kernel is 4.4.0.121 according to dpkg -l. I did fairly recently rolls back to an older kernel as the system didn't fully boot which didn't solve the problem (I created a new user instead). So I may have blindly followed some instruction and caused the current problem. 'Update-grub' and reboot did not solve the problem. As you can see I'm not an experienced user. How do I run kernel 4.4.0.121.

Other information: when I do remove old kernels with apt-get purge linux-image... ,I do get some error messages:
Error! Could not locate dkms.conf file.
File:  does not exist.
and
The link /vmlinuz.old is a damaged link
Removing symbolic link vmlinuz.old 
 you may need to re-run your boot loader[grub]
The link /initrd.img.old is a damaged link
Removing symbolic link initrd.img.old 
 you may need to re-run your boot loader[grub]

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by following instructions using a boot-repair tool at
https://www.howtogeek.com/114884/how-to-repair-grub2-when-ubuntu-wont-boot/
Uname is now giving the latest kernel version.